# Learning Android dev due to curiosity

Tags: android

Lately I have been thinking about developing some basic android app. Its only due to personal interest. Please guide me where to start from, what tools I require and any pointers to certain pdf's etc.

My background:

1) Embedded software developer in C.
2) Had got some chance to work on flex. Hence familiar with eclipse.
3) Working in multi-threaded environment. (RTOS)
4) Worked in unix/linux environment.

Since I have not worked on Java, how bad is it for me to get started?

Please guide me, I am ready to start with the very basics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to take a look at Android I recommend [this tutorial series](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/java-tutorial/) as it pretty much is made just for that. The very first information source is the official developer site. http://developer.android.com. It's full of very good articles and is a must read just to understand the platform. There also is the reference for the whole Android API on that site.

Of course StackOverflow is also on of the first places to *search* for answers if something isn't working and of course there is a chat on SO with an [Android room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15/android).

There are three good Java books I know about which you should maybe read before really starting advanced Android development. [Head First Java](http://www.headfirstlabs.com/books/hfjava/) from O'Reilly, [Thinking in Java 4th edition](http://mindview.net/Books/TIJ4) by Bruce Eckel and I forgot the name of third book but once I remember I will post it up.

If you decide to really start learning Android I'd recommend Mark Murphy's warescription on http://commonsware.com.

Answer (score 0):

I'd never used Eclipse or Java but just followed the official google android developer information to install and set up Eclipse with the extra plugins for Android and then just compilied the Hello World.

I then downloaded the code for an existing app that was close to what I wanted to try out (speed alerts using database of signs and built in GPS) and began modifying it.

Basic Java syntax is similiar to C - all you need to do is then understand all the OOP bits :)

I then decided I needed a program to do something so I decided to write that as a standard Java (non-android) app to get more into understanding Java.

I used [this](http://math.hws.edu/javanotes/) tutorial for that - it might be a bit slow for you :)

regards
Simon